# Find the roots of $P( z) =2z^{3} +( 9+6i) z^{2} +( 17+3i) z+12-9i$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I need to get all the roots of $P( z) =2z^{3} +( 9+6i) z^{2} +( 17+3i) z+12-9i$ but I dont know how to get the first factor!

Guessing numbers I got that $i$ is one of the roots but is there any systematic way to get the roots? Thanks!

Comment: If you know one root, use the factor theorem to reduce the problem to solving a quadratic instead. (Having said that, $z=1$ is _not_ a root. Maybe you meant $z=i$, which _is_ a root.)

Comment: Systematic way… Maybe Cardano formula, which is kind of complicated to use, but it exists.

Comment: I know I can do that, but my question is, is there any way to have gotten that root without trying to guess it?

Comment: As @xbh said, [it's complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) if you can't spot a root first. But if you can, use [my suggestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem). As I've noted in edits to that older comment, the root you meant is probably $z=i$, not $z=1$.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I wrote the wrong root, anyway, do you know if I can use the rational root theorem using the real part of $12-9i$?

Comment: This is never a polynomial with rational coefficients, so that cannot work.

Comment: The rational root theorem actually can be carried over to Gaussian integer coefficients. The numerator would be a Gaussian-integer of the constant and the denominator would be a factor of the leading coefficient. The only problem is that this generates a lot of distinct candidates, I believe 72 of them for this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Assume that the polynomial has at least one real root (this might not necessarily be true). Then we have

$$P(z)=2z^{3} +( 9+6i) z^{2} +( 17+3i) z+12-9i$$

$$=(2z^3+9z^2+17z+12)+i(6z^2+3z-9)=R(z)+i I(z)$$

Solving the polynomial $I(z)$ gives us the roots

$$I(z)=0\Rightarrow z=-\frac{3}{2}\text{ or }z=1$$

Testing both of these with the real polynomial gives

$$R(1)=40\text{ and }R(-3/2)=0$$

Alright, so we have one root. We can then assume the polynomial is of the form

$$P(z)=\left(z+\frac{3}{2}\right)(az^2+bz+c)$$

Expanding and solving gives us

$$a=2$$

$$b=6+6i$$

$$c=8-6i$$

This gives us a quadratic

$$f(z)=2z^2+(6+6i)z+(8 - 6 I)$$

Solving this using the quadratic formula gives us the other roots $i$ and $-3-4i$.

Answer (score 0):

In a first time try z=a where a is real number.

And so solve $2\,{z}^{3}+9\,{z}^{2}+17\,z+12=0$ and $6\,i{z}^{2}+3\,iz-9\,i=0$

You find a root.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

HINT...you could start by speculatively assuming that one of the roots is real.

If such a root exists, then it must be a root of the cubic formed by the real part of your polynomial, and also a root of the quadratic formed by the imaginary part.

This reveals that, for example, $z=-\frac32$ is a root.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that one of the zeroes of $ \ P( z) \ = \ 2z^3 \ + \ (9+6i) z^2 \ + \ (17+3i)z \ + \ (12-9i) \ $ is very important in that it brings a solution for the other zeroes just within the range of tractability *with* the additional assumption that one of  those is real.

If we have one real zero $ \ r \ \ , \ $ a second zero $ \ \beta·i \ $ is purely imaginary, and the remaining zero is $ \ \gamma + \delta·i \ \ (\beta \ , \ \gamma \ , \ \delta \ $ real)  ,  then the factorization $$ \ (z - r)·(z - \beta·i)·(z - \gamma - \delta·i) $$ $$ = \ \ z^3 \ + \ \left(\frac92 \ + \ 3i \right)·z^2 \ + \ \left(\frac{17}{2} \ + \ \frac32i \right)·z \ + \ \left(6 \ - \ \frac92i \right) $$

leads us to $ \ r·\beta·\delta \ = \ 6 \ \ , \ \ r·\beta·\gamma \ = \ \frac92 \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{\gamma}{\delta} \ = \ \frac34 \ \ , \ $ permitting us to express the complex zero as $ \ k·(3 + 4i) \ \ , \ $ with $ \ k \ $ being a real number.  The product of the other zeros is then
$$ r·\beta i  \ \ = \ \ \frac{-6 \ + \ \frac92i}{k·(3 \ + \ 4i)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{(-6 \ + \ \frac92i)·(3 \ - \ 4i)}{25·k} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ \frac{75}{2}i}{25·k} \ \ = \ \ \frac{3}{2k}·i \ \ . $$

The sum of the three zeroes is then
$$ r \ + \ \beta·i \ + \ (3k \ + \ 4k·i) \ \ = \ \ (r \ + \ 3k) \ + \ \left( \ 4k \ + \ \frac{3}{2rk} \ \right)·i \ \ = \ \ -\frac92 \ - \ 3i \ \ .   $$

This presents us with a system of two equations, one non-linear, to solve.  Using $ \ r \ = \  -\frac92  -  3k \ \ $ obtained for the real parts in the previous equation, "matching" the imaginary parts leads to
$$ 4k·2rk \ + \ 3·2rk \ + \  3 \ \ = \ \ 8k^2·\left(-\frac92 \ - \ 3k \right) \ + \ 6k·\left(-\frac92 \ - \ 3k \right) \ + \  3 \ \ . $$

$$ = \ \ -24k^3  \ - \ 54k^2  \ - \ 27k  \ + \  3 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$

a cubic equation which (happily) has the rational root $ \ k \ = \ -1 \ \ $ (the other roots are irrational -- $ \ \frac{-5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{33}}{8} \ $ -- about which more shortly).  This result gives the zeroes of $ \ P(z) \ $ as
$$ (-1)·(3 \ + \ 4i) \ = \ -3 \ - \ 4i \ \ \ , \ \ \ r \ = \ -\frac92 \ - \ 3·(-1) \ = \ -\frac32 \ \ \ , $$ $$ \beta i  \  = \  \frac{3}{2·\left(-\frac32 \right)·(-1)}·i \ \ = \ \ 1·i \ \ . $$

We did not assume them to be such, but fortunately all of the real and imaginary parts turn out to be integers or rational numbers.  You did not provide the source of this problem:  it looks like it was intended to place the zeroes of $ \ P(z) \ $ just within reach of being found "by hand".  Were two of the complex zeroes to have non-real real parts (much less the polynomial having *three* such zeroes), it would be far more difficult to describe a method for determining them.

[As for the irrational results we found for $ \ k \ \ , \ $ while we obtain supposed values for the three zeroes
$$ k \ = \ \frac{-5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{33}}{8} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ = \ \frac{-21 \ \mp \ 3\sqrt{33}}{8} \ \ \ , \ \ \ \gamma  +  \delta·i \ = \ \left(\frac{-5 \ \pm \ \sqrt{33}}{8} \right)·(3 \ + \ 4i) \ \ , $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ rk \ = \ \frac{3}{32}·(1 \ \mp \ \sqrt{33}) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \beta·i \ = \ \left(\frac{-1 \ \mp \ \sqrt{33}}{2} \right)·i \ \ \ , $$

which do indeed satisfy the conditions $   \ r·\beta·\delta \ = \ 6 \ \ , \ \ r·\beta·\gamma \ = \ \frac92 \ \ , \ $ none of them serve as roots of $ \ P(z) \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  So these irrational values for $ \ k \ $ are "spurious" solutions of the original problem.]